# How to output an HTML page based on user input

Tags: php, html

I want to make an HTML (or php maybe?) page that constructs a new HTML page based on input parameters the user gives to a drop-down box. I just don't know how you handle the input.

Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
         <input type="number" min="1">
    </body>
</html>
```

Yes I know it's not the full HTML page, but I just want to focus on the `<input>` tag. I know you probably have to set it equal to a  PHP variable maybe?

I want it to generate a different HTML page that looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
         <p>You have chosen: $input </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I might be asking this all wrong, but I hope it makes sense what I'm looking for. I need to know how to handle the user input. I couldn't find a thread that discusses this. Do I need to generate a new HTML file? Or just override the current one and maybe have a reset button? I'm so confused.

Comment: `if(!empty($input)) echo $input; else echo '<input type="number" min="1>';`? Somewhat unclear of what you are asking

Comment: An HTML page with form elements like `input` requires a `form` tag, with a method to submit that form data - HTML 101

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the simple case, you'll have two pages: your form and your result page. You can send data from the form page to the results page with one of two methods: GET or POST.

GET means that the data you're sending gets put in the page URL. This is useful because then you can link to a specific version of the results page, but potentially dangerous because you don't want to put sensitive data in the URL bar.

POST means that the data is sent with the HTTP request in the background. This is preferable for something like a password.

The GET and POST data can be read by nearly any server-side language and used to generate HTML on-the-fly. The example below uses PHP.

The form page doesn't necessarily need any server-side code, just basic HTML. Here's a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <form method="GET" action="my_result.php">
    <input type="text" name="my_value">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</html>
```

Your second page (the results page) should bear the name that you specified in the form's `action` attribute. This is the page which will need server-side code. So here is an example `my_result.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <p><?php echo $_GET['my_value']; ?></p>
</html>
```

Obviously, `my_value` can and should be replaced by whatever you want to call your data, as long as the `name` attribute of the input element matches the key in the PHP.

This example uses the GET method. You can use POST by changing the `method` attribute of the form and using `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` (if you are using PHP).

If you use `$_REQUEST` rather than `$_GET` or `$_POST`, it finds a value that was passed via either GET *or* POST. This is usually less safe than explicitly stating how your value was passed.

---

Addendum: Some servers are configured to disallow you from directly using the values of php superglobals such as `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_REQUEST` for security purposes. That is because you really should *always* sanitize user input before using it in an application. The type of sanitization required depends on the type of input and how it is being used, and is well outside of the scope of this question. For this purpose, php provides the [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function.

The sanitization filter is an optional parameter for the `filter_input` function, so if you *really* want to use the data unfiltered, you can simply omit it (but know that this is dangerous). In this case, you can replace all instances of `$_GET['my_value']` in the above code with `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'my_value')`.

Comment: This is REALLY helpful but I'm getting an error where it says I can't access a superglobal directly

Comment: @katie1245 that has to do with how your web host has configured their php install. it seems they have enabled some settings to tighten security. the purpose of the error is to encourage you to use [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) to sanitize your input before using it.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a tutorial, but I guide you to some important points:

1. You can get user input with html by using form element. read more about form and methods of form (GET and POST).
2. Then, how can you print user input when submitted by user? php supports both (GET and POST) using $_GET and $_POST with input name as key.
3. Dealing with user-input needs extra care because of security. user might submit malicious content that later attacks you or another user.

Answer (score 1):

To handle a user input you have to use [forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

```
<form action="action_page.php">
  <input type="number" min="1 name="my-number">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After user set number and press submit button, you will get the value in action_page.php in *$_REQUEST['my-number']*

Answer (score 1):

Try like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

if ($_POST) {
    echo "<h3>You have selected ".$_POST['number']."</h3>";
} else {
    echo '
    <form method="post" action="">
        <select name="number" id="number">
            <option value="1" >1</option>
            <option value="2" >2</option>
            <option value="3" >3</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    ';
}

?>


</body>
</html>
```